# How to use preFocus in extJS Tagfield

Tags: javascript, extjs, placeholder, extjs6

I need to set some Value in my tagfield. When I am debugging then I am geeting `tag.getValue();`

I am getting array of values.  So Ideally I do not need to set Value. But Value is appearing only after click on tagfield, in another word onFocus. But I need to show before click there for I am using `Placeholder`

like `tag.inputEl.set({'placeholder':tag.getValue()});`

Here it appearing. Can anybody tell me how to use PreFocus. So It can work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the dropdown menu of the tagfield with the [`expand()`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#method-expand) method. In addition to that you can listen to the [`collapse`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/classic/Ext.form.field.Tag.html#event-collapse) event to reopen the dropdown menu if the focus is lost.

Here is an example for that:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21ao

---

Same applies if you manually add some values to the selection:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21ap   (tag is added after 3 seconds)

---

If you want to user the placeholder to indicate which options are available, then you can listen to the change event to update the placeholder text.

Here an example:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/21aq